# Limit 3G traffic on Jailbroken iPad

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

Is there any software for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed apps used to help you monitor and control your data usage over 3G. A quick Google search found this option: [Data Usage for iPhone](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/06/app-directory-the-best-data-usage-tracker-for-iphone/).